# Init code for reading and writing SD card with MCS51?

Tags: microcontroller, atmel, keil

Do you know how to interface SD card with MCS51, 
AT89S52 with SD card and 
code example in Keil if there's any...

Thanks for the info...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SD cards can be accessed either using

- the full 4 bit wide data bus, 
  or via
- SPI (serial peripheral interface)

The latter one (SPI) has lower throughput but it is a very simple interface commonly used between micro controller and periherals ICs.

The simplified version of the physical layer of the SD card spec
gives you more detailed info: see download area of https://www.sdcard.org/

There is also an [aplication note](http://alumni.cs.ucr.edu/~amitra/sdcard/Additional/sdcard_appnote_foust.pdf) by TI that explains how to access SD cards via SPI using their MSP430 µC and might be very helpful even though you are using a different µC.